# Ubuntu 18.04 "Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied" when trying to reboot from script that is run by cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron, reboot

I have a Python program that reboots the computer after some errors:

**main.py:**

```
import os

if (some_error):
    os.system('/sbin/reboot')
```

In order for this to work I added `NOPASSWD` to sudoers file for the user that runs this script:

**/etc/sudoers:**

```
adam ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/reboot
```

The Python program is executed via simple bash script that keeps it running in case of a crash:

**run.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

myscript(){
    python3 main.py > log 2>&1
}

until myscript; do
    echo "program crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

and the `run.sh` script is executed via cron file on reboot:

**/etc/cron.d/my_cron_file:**

```
@reboot adam cd /home/adam && ./run.sh
```

Now here is my problem: When I run the `run.sh` or `main.py` directly from CLI, it works and reboots just fine. But when I run it via the cron file on @reboot it outputs:

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

When I check processes with `ps aux` it runs under the `adam` user who clearly has `/sbin/reboot` rights since it works when run from CLI. So why does it not work when run with cron?

Comment: `NOPASSWD` doesn't mean you can omit `sudo`